# method execute after custom execption

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have a custom exception after a condition, in the background of this method I was creating in object customers, but I have a condition when the customers phone hasn't found it he shows me a list in exception 
when he shows me the exception the creation stopped but when i delete the exception everything will be okey how to fix that

```
           try:
               raise exceptions.Warning("List of customers you need to register : \n'' %s'" % (ids_customer))
           except Exception:
                pass
```

i use this one but the pop up doesn't display

Comment: I did not understand very well your point, but did you tried use **finally**? You can see a little bit in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions), may help you. I think this would solve your problem

Comment: What do you mean exactly if you raise exception than catch it in the same time odoo will not stop the transactions and the saving happen normally